# The Tools dropdown does not show in menubar - TinyMCE 4.0.5 jQuery version

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I have recently upgraded to tinyMCE 4 and prefer to use the jQuery version. However, in the menu bar i cannot get the "Tools" menu to show up.  i have used the javascript version and it shows, but once i put the jQuery version in it disappears.

My initialization code is as follows:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
  script_url : 'tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
  width : 900,
  height : 500,
  oninit : "setInst",
  theme: "modern",
  plugins: ["table paste"],
  menubar: 'format edit table tools',
  toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist",
  image_advtab: true
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in console.

Comment: i have figured it out... i was missing "code" in the plugins. thanks for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046208/tinymce-customize-file-menubar/19859366#19859366