# Tiny MCE - Remove 'FIle' option from Menu

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce, rich-text-editor

Does anyone know how to remove just the option "File" from the Menu Bar.

[image]

I have tried this way :

```
menu: {
edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
       }
```

It works but I want to retain all options in Menu except "File".

In stead of specifying each and every menu option and its sub options of what all we need, is there a way to specify just what we **do not** need from the menu?

Something like "remove" ?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Possible solutions are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033321/remove-menu-and-status-bars-in-tinymce-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046208/tinymce-customize-file-menubar

Comment: I believe they have it in their documentation. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure this with the `menubar` [option](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menubar).

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  menubar: 'edit insert view format table tools'  // skip file
});
```

Comment: Sure, Thanks Again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046208/tinymce-customize-file-menubar) might help you.It,s not exact your answer but, you will get helo how to customize the menu bar of TINyMce